# Как следующий скрипт .VBS выполнить через C#?

Tags: c#, vbscript

Вот скрипт на .VBS

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "data\tor.exe -f data\torrc -SocksPort 9001 -ControlPort 8001 - DataDirectory data\torf1", 0
WshShell = Null
```

Нужно выполнить его на c#

Так попробовал - не работает

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"H:\tor-proxy\data\tor.exe", @"-f data\torrc - SocksPort 9001 -ControlPort 8001 -DataDirectory data\torf1");
```

Трудно ли это сделать?

Comment: Как `не работает`? Что выдает? Ошибки есть?

Comment: Процесс не создается в диспетчере задач, в случае с powershell - создается

Comment: Рабочую директорию указывали с параметрами запуска процесса?

Comment: В имени Process.Start сразу указал директорию и сам exe

Comment: Process.Start(@"H:\tor-proxy\data\tor.exe", @" -f H:\tor-proxy\data\torrc - SocksPort 9001 - ControlPort 8001 - DataDirectory H:\tor-proxy\data\torf1");    Так тоже не работает

Comment: В вас там точно нет лишних пробелов? `-<вот здесь>SocksPort`

Comment: А вы powershell и vbs случайно не путаете? Как бы ваш первый скрипт корректным скриптом powershell не является...

Comment: Блин, точно .vbs

Comment: Надо смотреть под отладчиком и проверить корректность путей, правильность аргументов. При старте он возвращает null или все же конструируется какой-то объект?